# Image Stored in Internal storage in Xamarin Android but i can't getting image from Internal memory

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I successfully store image to Internal storage but In Android i can not Display Image from Internal storage,

My Code For storage in **Xamarin.Android**:

```
public void SavePictureToDisk"ProfilePicture", byte[] imageData)
    {            
        var pictures = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pictures, "ProfilePicture"+".png");
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, imageData);
            File fl = new File(filePath);         
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I successfully store image to internal storage in Android.
My Code to access file stored in **Xamarin.Forms**

```
public async void ImageDisplay()
{
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFile imgfile1 = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("ProfilePicture.png");
        ImgUser.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imgfile1.Path);
}
```

But image Display blank.please help me.i have tried lot of but i don't get anything.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you declared all the required permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I have added Permission which  require i can get  some of the image stored in internal storage but  some image not Display.

Comment: Hey! Are you able to provide a copy of the app in some way? I want to see if I can figure out what is going on.

Comment: What permission is required to read & write files?